# Get folder in Android application, that was not created via this App

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Having Google Drive account with folders and files. I want to make android application for adding and geting files to there. Class [QUERY](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/query/Query.html) is useful, but it can work with data making by application only

> The Android Drive API only works with the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file scope. This means that only files which a user has opened or created with your application can be matched by a query.

Help, please, how can I add files to any folder, that was created via webinterface early?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the latest google API, it was just released a few weeks ago.  It currently only works with the drive.file scope, hasn't yet implemented a number of capabilities (e.g. setting multiple parents), and in my experience, contains some bugs that need to be fixed as well.

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient
```

Use this API instead:

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive

    try {


        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
        scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata");
        scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);

        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(m_context, scopes);
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(m_account.name);          


        //Get token cannot be run from the main thread;
        //Trying to get a token right away to see if we are authorized

        token = credential.getToken();

        if(token == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "token is null");
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "GDrive token: " + token);
            g_drive = new Drive.Builder(
                          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                          new GsonFactory(), credential).build();

     } catch ( UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
       ....
     }
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, so where can i get Tutorial about this API? i can't find how work with GoogleAccountCredential

Comment: I searched for a bit, but unfortunately not seeing a good guide.  Google's already moved its [android guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) to the new API; the closest using the "serivices" api is the regular java guide [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-java).  The main difference is when you call credential.getToken(), and fail, googlePlayServices returns an exception, which contains an intent your app can catch and run to prompt the user to give you permission.

Comment: btw the new [android guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) also has the google account credential.  Its a different version, but nearly identical -- the main difference I noted is it returns a "UserRecoverableAuthIOException" -- note the "IO";

Answer (score 3):

You want to avoid using full drive scope unless you really need it.  Users much prefer that your app have a narrower scope, as it makes it easier to trust you with their data.  There are a couple of methods that you can accomplish most folder use cases while still only requiring file scope:

Use the [OpenFileActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/OpenFileActivityBuilder.html) to have the user select the folder that they want the file to be added to.

You can do this by configuring the OpenFileActivityBuilder to only display the folder mimetypes.

```
 IntentSender intent = driveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
    .setActivityTitle("Pick a destination folder")
    .setMimeType(new String[] { DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE } })
    .build();
 startIntentSenderForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
```

Alternatively, if you have a corresponding web app that created the folder, just use the same developer console entry for both apps and you should already have access to the folder.

Comment: Hi Cheryl, our case is quite different. We intent to offer user a private/ personal cloud storage. The data we store is generated by different apps (Desktop app, mobile app, ...). Hence, if we were using drive.file, our mobile app will not able to access data uploaded by desktop app. Currently, Java Drive SDK (It has drive scope) serves us well, but not API offered by Google Play Service (It only has drive.file scope). I was wondering, does Google team has intention to expand to scope to drive scope, for Google Play Service? Thanks.

Comment: Your mobile and desktop versions of your app should share the same app id, and thus be able to share access to files created by each other.  Just use one entry in the cloud console for both.